# Failure to set up mailer in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to get a Rails mailer working but I get the following error message when I try to sign up a new user and send the activation email. I'm following chapter 10 of Hartl's latest (3rd ed.) railstutorial so in theory it should be working:

```
No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"account_activations", :email=>"joe@bloggmail.com", :format=>nil, :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]

app/views/user_mailer/account_activation.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_user_mailer_account_activation_html_erb__1296124105699284853_2236858900'

app/mailers/user_mailer.rb:6:in `account_activation'

app/models/user.rb:82:in `send_activation_email'

app/controllers/users_controller.rb:27:in `create'
```

The relevant bits of code are:

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :remember_token, :activation_token
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :callsign, :use => :slugged
  has_secure_password
  before_save do
    self.email.downcase!
    self.callsign.downcase!
  end
  before_create do
    :create_activation_digest
  end
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(?:\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence:   true,
                    format:     { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  VALID_CALLSIGN_REGEX = /\A[a-z\d\-.\_]+\z/i
  validates :callsign, presence:   true,
                       length:     { maximum: 20 },
                       format:     { with: VALID_CALLSIGN_REGEX },
                       uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }
  validates :slug, presence: true

  # Returns the hash digest of the given string.
  def self.digest(string)
    cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST :
                                                  BCrypt::Engine.cost
    BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
  end

  # Returns a random token.
  def self.new_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end

  # Remembers a user in the database for use in persistent sessions.
  def remember
    self.remember_token = User.new_token
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(remember_token))
  end

  # Forgets a user.
  def forget
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, nil)
  end

  # Returns true if the given token matches the digest.
  def authenticated?(attribute, token)
    digest = send("#{attribute}_digest")
    return false if digest.nil?
    BCrypt::Password.new(digest).is_password?(token)
  end

  # Activates an account.
  def activate
    update_attribute(:activated,    true)
    update_attribute(:activated_at, Time.zone.now)
  end

  # Sends activation email.
  def send_activation_email
    UserMailer.account_activation(self).deliver_now
  end

  private

    # Creates and assigns the activation token and digest.
    def create_activation_digest
      self.activation_token  = User.new_token
      self.activation_digest = User.digest(activation_token)
    end

end
```

Users controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  before_action :logged_in_user,     only: [:index, :show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :non_logged_in_user, only: [:new, :create]
  before_action :correct_user,       only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :admin_user,         only: :destroy

  def index
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def show
    @user = User.friendly.find(params[:id])
    @page_name = "user_page"
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      @user.send_activation_email
      flash[:info] = "Please check your email to activate your account."
      redirect_to root_url      
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end # create

  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if ( current_user != @user )
      @user.destroy
      flash[:success] = "User deleted."
      redirect_to users_url
    else
      redirect_to @user, notice: "Suicide is not permitted, admin chappie. Hard cheese."
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end # update

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :callsign, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end

    # Before filters

    def non_logged_in_user
      if logged_in?
        redirect_to root_url, notice: "Nice try pal. You can't create a new user 
                                       if you're already signed in."
      end
    end

    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
    end

    def admin_user
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
    end

end
```

account_activation.html.erb:

```
<h1>MySite</h1>

<p>Hi <%= @user.name %>,</p>

<p>
Welcome! Click on the link below to activate your account:
</p>

<%= link_to "Activate", edit_account_activation_url(@user.activation_token,
                                                    email: @user.email) %>
```

user_mailer.rb:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "noreply@mysite.com"

  def account_activation(user)
    @user = user
    mail to: user.email, subject: "Account activation"
  end

  def password_reset
    @greeting = "Hi"

    mail to: "to@example.org"
  end
end
```

routes.rb:

```
Mysite::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :users
  resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
  root                'static_pages#home'
  get    'help'    => 'static_pages#help'
  get    'about'   => 'static_pages#about'
  get    'contact' => 'static_pages#contact'
  get    'signup'  => 'users#new'
  get    'login'   => 'sessions#new'
  post   'login'   => 'sessions#create'
  delete 'logout'  => 'sessions#destroy'

end
```

EDIT:
account_activations_controller.rb:

```
class AccountActivationsController < ApplicationController

  def edit
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
    if user && !user.activated? && user.authenticated?(:activation, params[:id])
      user.activate
      log_in user
      flash[:success] = "Account activated!"
      redirect_to user
    else
      flash[:danger] = "Invalid activation link"
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Please post your account activations controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using this in your routes file instead of resources:

```
get 'account_activation', "account_activations#edit", :as => :edit_account_activation
```

...and deal with the secret token and email address params there.

Right now the problem is that you don't have a controller action to match the route you're using in the account_activation.html.erb

Comment: Thank you, you were correct, but I had to use the following code:
`get 'account_activation' => 'account_activations#edit', :as => :edit_account_activation`
The question is, why didn't `edit_account_activation_url(@user.activation_token, email: @user.email) %>` in account_activation.html.erb create the correct route? Doesn't this send the request to the edit_account_activation_path, which was created by `resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]` in the routes file?

Comment: Bazley, even though you've called the route helper, it still has to be defined in your routes.rb file, or you'll get an error. You can't create routes in your views that aren't defined in your routes file. Glad I could help.

Comment: This is what I don't understand - the original code should have worked shouldn't it? Because it IS defined in the routes file: the code:
`resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]`
creates the named route edit_account_activation_path, which hits the edit action in the account_activations controller?

Comment: Have you tried resource_path instead of resources_path?

Answer (score 0):

Found the error.
The problem was this bit of code in class User:

```
before_create do
  :create_activation_digest
end
```

It should be:

```
before_create do
  create_activation_digest
end
```

Or:

```
before_create :create_activation_digest
```

Schoolboy error. I apologise for wasting everyone's time.

(Therefore the code:

```
resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
```

in routes.rb does indeed create the correct route)